# Model Sim verilog error Illegal output or inout port connection for port 'out2'

Tags: input, connection, output, verilog, modelsim

Here is my full code for a 64-bit multiplier. It is giving error at full_multiplier line 17 that I have emboldened (3 stars). The error is vsim-3053  Illegal output or inout port connection for port 'out2'.

```
 module full_multiplier(input [63:0] a, b, input [1:0] select, input clk, output reg [63:0] out);

        wire [10:0] exp;
        wire state;
        wire out1;
        wire [51:0] man;
        wire sign;



            check_zero ch1( a, b, 2'b10, clk,state);    
            check_sign c1(sign,a,b,clk,state);      
        addexp a1(exp, a, b,clk,state);            
        mul1 m1( man, a, b, clk,state);         

        **normalize n1(out, sign, exp, man, clk);**


    endmodule


    module check_zero (input [63:0] a, b, input [1:0] select, input clk,  output reg state);

    parameter done = 1'b0, next= 1'b1;


    always @(posedge clk) begin
    if ((a[51:0] == 0) && (b[51:0] == 0)) begin  
              //out <= 64'b0;
              state <= done;

    end else if (a[51:0]==0 && select==0) begin
        //  out <= b;
              state <= done;
    end else if (b[51:0]==0 && select==0) begin
        //  out <= a;
              state <= done;

    end else if (a[51:0]==0 && select==1) begin
        //  out[63] <= ~b[63];
        //  out[62:0] <= ~b[62:0];
              state <= done;
    end else if (b[51:0]==0 && select==1) begin
        //  out <= a;
              state <= done;

    end else if (a[51:0]==0 && select==2) begin
        //  out <= 0;
              state <= done;
    end else if (b[51:0]==0 && select==2) begin
        //  out <= 0;
              state <= done;

    end else if (a[51:0]==0 && select==3) begin
        //  out <= 0;
              state <= done;
    end else if (b[51:0]==0 && select==3) begin
        //    out[63] <= 1;
            //    out[62:52] <= 2047;
            //    out[51] <= 1;
            //    out[50:0] <= 0;
                state <= done;
    end else begin
        state<=next;
    end
    end
    endmodule

    module check_sign(output reg sign,
            input [63:0]   x,
            input [63:0]   y,
        input clk,
        input state);

    always@ (posedge clk) begin
    if (state==1) begin

    sign <= y[63] ^ x[63];

    end else begin
    sign =0;
    end
    end
    endmodule

    module addexp(output reg [10:0] exp,
            input [63:0]   x,
            input [63:0]   y,
        input clk,
        input state);

    always@ (posedge clk) begin
    if (state==1) begin

    exp <= x[62:52] + y[62:52]- 1023;

    end else begin
    exp <=1023;
    end
    end
    endmodule

    module mul1(
            output reg [51:0]  c,
    //  output reg [7:0] addexp,
            input [63:0]   x,
            input [63:0]   y,
        input clk,
        input state); 

    reg [103:0] p;
    reg [103:0]a;
    integer i;

    always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (state==1) begin
      a=x;
      p=0; // needs to zeroed
      for(i=0;i<51;i=i+1) begin
        if(y[i]) begin
          p=p+a; // must be a blocking assignment
        end
        a=a<<1;
      end

      for(i=103;i>=0;i=i-1) begin
        if (p[i]) begin
          c=p[i+:52]; 
        //  addexp=i-51;
         p=0;
        end
       end
    end else begin
     c=0;
    end
    end
    endmodule


    module normalize(output reg [63:0] out2,
            input    sign,
            input [10:0]   exp,
        input [51:0] man,
        input clk);

    always@ (posedge clk) begin

    out2 <= {sign,exp,man};
    end
    endmodule

module tb_mul1;

reg [63:0] a;

reg [63:0] b;
reg clk;
wire [63:0] out;

full_multiplier m1 ( a, b,2'b10, clk, out);

initial #200 $finish;
initial begin clk=0; forever #5 clk=~clk; end

initial begin

    a = 64'h000_0_0000_0000_0000;
    b = 64'h000_0_0000_0000_0000;
    #20;

    #20;
    b = 64'h080_8_0000_0000_0001;
    a = 64'h080_F_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF;
    #60 b = 64'h080_8_0000_0000_0003;
    #60 b = 64'h081_8_0000_0000_0000;
    #60 a = 64'h080_8_0000_0040_0000;
    #60 b = 64'h090_8_0000_0000_0001;
    #60 a = 64'h880_8_0000_0040_0000;
    #60 a = 64'h890_8_0000_0040_0000;
    #60 a = 64'h890_8_0000_0000_0001;
    #60 b = 64'h890_8_0000_0000_0001;
    #60 b = 64'h890_1_0000_0000_0000;


    #60 $stop;
end


endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

In your top level module you've declared the signal out to be a reg:

```
module full_multiplier(input [63:0] a, b, input [1:0] select, input clk, output reg [63:0] out);
```

That appears to be because you used to be assigning to that signal in that module.  Now you are instead getting the value for that signal from an output port of normalize. That means that out should now simply be using a wire and not a reg. If you change the module to be (remove the reg):

```
module full_multiplier(input [63:0] a, b, input [1:0] select, input clk, output [63:0] out);
```

Then it should compile.